# JavaScript- display whole object and specific keys and its value

Tags: javascript, object

I am using this code

```
var obj  =  {   'name':'Some Person Name',
                'country':'Country of Some Person',
                'age':1
            }
var storeVal = Object.keys(obj)

for (var i = 0; i < storeVal.length; i++) {
    var storeLoop = storeVal[i] ;
    document.write('<pre>'+storeLoop+'</pre>');
}
```

Now I can display the keys of object `obj` using above code and I also know how to display values of object `obj` using `Object.values()`. I want to know how I can display the whole object `obj` using above `for` loop and I am not talking about `for..in` loop. I want to also know how to display the specific **key** and **value**,for example if I want to display only **name key** and **its value**,how that can be done ? I am only using JavaScript. No jquery.

Comment: You keep saying you don't want a `for-in` loop, but then you use constructs that provide nearly the same semantics as `for-in`. Why is that?

Comment: @squint I am in my initial stage of learning JavaScript. I did not even use `for..in` loop in my entire learning since I started learning JavaScript. I do not know about the constructs of `for..in`, I just want to understand only `for` loop properly and then I'll go for variations like `for..in`. I am just freaking clearing my concepts properly.

Comment: Settle down pal. I'm the one who was fighting to keep your previous question open. But if you ask how to do things that are inherently misguided, you're going to get people inquiring about them so that they don't send you down the wrong path. If you want to understand `for` properly, that's great, but that has nothing to do with enumerating objects.

Comment: I know you were on my side and I appreciate that. Thanks for that and I will keep your point in mind when I ask  questions next time.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var obj  =  {   'name':'Some Person Name',
                'country':'Country of Some Person',
                'age':1
            }
var storeVal = Object.keys(obj)

for (var i = 0; i < storeVal.length; i++) {
    var storeLoop = storeVal[i] + ': ' + obj[storeVal[i]];
    document.write('<pre>'+storeLoop+'</pre>');
}

// Just displaying a certain key:

document.write('<pre>Name: '+obj.name+'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use variable names which reflects their content, then I suggest to declare all variables first, an not for example inside of a `for` loop.

For getting the value of a property of an object, you could use one of two syntax as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
object.property     // dot notation
object['property']  // bracket notation
```

To get a value of the object, you could use

```
object.name  // 'Some Person Name'
```

```js
var object = { name: 'Some Person Name', country: 'Country of Some Person', age: 1 },
    keys = Object.keys(object),
    value,
    i, 
    nameKey = 'name';

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    value = object[keys[i]];
    document.write('<pre>' + keys[i] + ': ' + value + '</pre>');
}

document.write('<hr><pre>' + nameKey + ': ' + object[nameKey] + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I wanted to display the whole object like @Schlaus done in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for you and you don't really want to output it in the HTML code, you can use `console.log(storeVal);` and explore the printed object in your browser console.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` , see [MDN-Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Basic example:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]
```

Your code:

```
var obj  =  {   'name':'Some Person Name',
                'country':'Country of Some Person',
                'age':1
            }

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // Do whatever you like with key and value
});
```